# Stack Exchange site layout question

Tags: support, stackauth

I noticed that the new SE sites all have the same layout and the same image.  When will these things be changed?  I don't want to support these sites in my application, [StackTop](http://www.mattsapps.com/stacktop/), until I know the icon and the color scheme because I do all the logic for the backgrounds manually, without using StackAuth.  If I create a default color scheme, then it looks like I don't fully support that site, and well, it could lead to some confusion because half the sites look the same.

Answer (score 3):

See the answer to the meta question [Will all Stack Exchange sites look the same?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same)

To quote Robert Cartaino:

> When a site makes it out of beta, they will choose their own logo and design.

Comment: when do sites come out of beta?

Comment: @Matt: It looks like it could range quite a bit.  "1 month, possibly many more" according to Jeff.  See: [What is the minimum length of time a proposed site will be in its beta phase?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/54633/what-is-the-minimum-length-of-time-a-proposed-site-will-be-in-its-beta-phase)